# Already installed PyCharm is not shown on new JetBrains Toolbox

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-toolbox

My system is running Arch Linux, and PyCharm 2016.3 is already installed on my system.

I downloaded the latest JetBrains Toolbox today. But in the all tools menu, Toolbox shows PyCharm isn't installed on my system.

What's going on here?  Could anyone help me resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The toolbox app doesn't show you any of Jetbrains products that you have installed outside of the app. You'll have to reinstall the application using the toolbox app of you like your applications shown there.

See the first question and answer at https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/05/25/introducing